# python version 2.3 substitution for Queue.Queue.task_done()

Tags: python, multithreading, queue

I found a piece of code online demoing Queued multithreading in Python.
http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577187-python-thread-pool/
I Tried it, it seems to work.
Except I'm running python version 2.3.
After a thread completes it complains for have no attribute 'task_done' 'join' 
I googled around and found Queue.task_done() and Queue.join() come with version 2.5 or later.
What's my best option in this case?
FYI: I tried commenting out line 17: self.tasks.task_done()
It looks like the code can run to completion except seeing this error after each thread completes
        self.tasks.join()
    AttributeError: Queue instance has no attribute 'join'
I used 'top' to check the number of thread the program starts is exactly what I specified.
After the program finishes, the Linux shell become unresponsive.

Comment: Is there a compelling reason you're using 2.3?

Comment: I don't control which version of Python installed on my user machines.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to copy the Queue.py file from a more recent version of Python, and copy it into your project.  I don't know if the code relies on newer features or not, but if it doesn't, then you're all set.